# Moving back forward to current checkout

Tags: git

I wanted to move an individual file back to a previous commit but when I pasted commit code it did a carriage return and everything checked out to the previous commit.  (`git checkout <code>`)

Now when I go `git log` it doesn't show the commit in the future, just the commit I checked out.

How do I see the commit in the future so I can check it out again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run `git reflog` to see which branch/commit you were on. Then run `git checkout <branch>/<commit>`.

Or simply run `git checkout -` to go back to the previous branch/commit if you haven't run more checkouts.

After you return to the previous stage, use `git checkout <commit> -- <file_path>` to checkout only the file(s) you specify in `<file_path>` of the revision `<commit>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out your branch name to get back to where you were. Assuming you were on the `master` branch:

```
git checkout master
```